# How to pass html parameter in Google Closure Template

Tags: closures, google-closure-templates

Guys I want to pass a parameter that contains html characters in `Google Closure Template`, but all I get is literal html texts. How to do this?

What I have tried so far is this :

```
{template .modal autoescape="strict" kind="html"}
   {$html_content}
{/template}
```

I have been reading [this](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/security#in_html) but it's not very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
{template .modal}
   {$html_content |noAutoescape}
{/template}
```

Is going to print your HTML. But consider that using `|noAutoescape` in your templates is discouraged.

> Discouraged: It's easy to accidentally introduce XSS attacks when the assertion
>   that content is safe is far away from where it is created. Instead,
>   wrap content as sanitized content where it is created and easy to
>   demonstrate safety.
> – [Google Closure Templates Functions and Print Directives](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/functions_and_directives#print_directives)

Or if you are sure `$html_content` is "safe" HTML, you can ordain it right where you pass parameters to the template:

```
goog.require('soydata.VERY_UNSAFE');
goog.require('template.namespace');

var container = document.getElementById('modal');
var html = '<strong>HTML you trust!</strong>';

container.innerHTML = template.namespace.modal({
  html_content: soydata.VERY_UNSAFE.ordainSanitizedHtml(html);
});
```

Then your initial template is going to print HTML as it is:

```
/**
 * @param html_content HTML markup
 */
{template .modal autoescape="strict" kind="html"}
   {$html_content}
{/template}
```